# What is the best way to 'unpack' JSON into a SQL Server table at the lowest level?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I had the following JSON blob:

```
{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Pets": [
    {
      "PetName": "Rex",
      "PetType": "Dog"
    },
    {
      "PetName": "Mittens",
      "PetType": "Cat"
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be the best way to unpack this into a table in SQL Server that looks like this:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
| FirstName | LastName | PetName | PetType |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
| John      | Smith    | Rex     | Dog     |
| John      | Smith    | Mittens | Cat     |
+-----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

The JSON I am actually dealing with is extremely large so would need to be done programmatically.

Comment: USE [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: From SQL Server 2016 you have built-in JSON support. What is your current SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse this JSON, you need to use `OPENJSON()` with `APPLY` or a combination of `OPENJSON()` and `JSON_VALUE()`. Note, that the statement depends on the JSON structure and you need at least SQL Server 2016:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Pets": [
    {
      "PetName": "Rex",
      "PetType": "Dog"
    },
    {
      "PetName": "Mittens",
      "PetType": "Cat"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Statement with `OPENJSON()` and additional `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT j1.FirstName, j1.LastName, j2.PetName, j2.PetType
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   FirstName varchar(50) '$.FirstName',
   LastName varchar(50) '$.LastName',
   Pets nvarchar(max) '$.FirtstName' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(@json, '$.Pets') WITH (
   PetName varchar(50) '$.PetName',
   PetType varchar(50) '$.PetType'
) j2
```

Statement with `OPENJSON()` and `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.FirstName') AS FirsttName,
   JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.LastName') AS LastName,
   PetName,
   PetType
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Pets') WITH (
   PetName varchar(50) '$.PetName',
   PetType varchar(50) '$.PetType'
)
```

Result:

```
FirsttName  LastName    PetName    PetType
John        Smith       Rex        Dog
John        Smith       Mittens    Cat
```